# Powershell script to copy folder from fileshare to a list of computers

Tags: powershell

I think I have this script right but I'm getting the expected results.  It runs, but the folder is not copying.  Purpose is to copy a folder on a fileshare to computers listed in a txt file on the same share.

```
$computers = Get-Content "\\tswkbro\shared\brookscomputers.txt"
$folderToCopy = "\\tswkbro\shared\abcbrooks-3.0.0.0\*.*"
Function Copy-ItemUNC   { New-PSDrive -Name "B" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\tswkbro\shared\" 
ForEach($computer in $Computers){
                Copy-Item -Path $folderToCopy -Destination "\\$computer\C$\" 
                }
            }
```

tried this too... no luck

```
$computers = Get-Content "\\tswkbro\shared\brookscomputers.txt"
$folderToCopy = "\\tswkbro\shared\abcbrooks-3.0.0.0\*.*"
Function Copy-ItemUNC   { New-PSDrive -Name "B" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\tswkbro\shared\" 
$Computers | ForEach-Object{
                Copy-Item -Path $folderToCopy -recurse -Destination "\\$computers\C$\" -Verbose -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                }
            }
```

Ran script but no results...

Comment: I mean, you're copying the contents of the folder to the root of `C:\ `.

Comment: getting same result when trying to put it in c:\Temp\  Feel like i have the destination syntax wrong

Comment: do you have any error message ? Why are you doing a `New-PSdrive` that you don't use ?

Comment: if you use `$Computers | ForEach-Object` the destination must be  `\\$_\C$\`